# NullPointerException in Silk4J Object Map Editor when pressing the Tab key

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, crash, silktest

After creating a new Silk4J Object Map entry manually (right click, "Insert new") and enter the item name, I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to move to the Locator path input field.

In this case, a series of "Object not set to an instance of an object" error messages appear. Eventually, Eclipse crashes. Doing some debugging, I found out that Eclipse crashes due to a StackOverflowException.

I can move to the locator path column using the mouse, but since I'm used to do things by keyboard, I'd really like to find a fix. How can I make the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key work as expected?

I am using Silk4J 16 Hotfix 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some more debugging, I found out that Silk4J for Eclipse (Java) actually uses a WPF user interface (.NET).

While preinstalled by Windows, I never needed .NET on my machine, so I never installed any updates for it.

Installing the latest .NET updates, the problem was gone. In my case I updated to .NET 4.5.2.